# Is there an API endpoint to find the drive of a private channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are looking into creating teams in our organization with prefilled folder structures in the files tab.

For normal channels this is easy, because the files lay in a directory named after the channel in the root SharePoint of the group. So we can do POST requests to the
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/root/children` endpoint and create the folders for the channels. The answer from the endpoint contains the ID of the new folders and we can move forward creating the folder structures for the channels using this id.

Private channels however are located outside the groups SharePoint.

The question is, is there a possibility to get the root of the drive with the information provided by the `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels` POST call which creates the private channel?

Comment: Please take a look at [Private Channel Sharepoint sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels#private-channel-sharepoint-sites).Meanwhile private channel is in developer preview.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Is it still in developer preview? According to [its uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16911079-support-for-private-channels) it is fully rolled out to public ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) navigational property of the Channel resource called `filesFolder`. From the Graph v1.0 endpoint:

```xml
<EntityType Name="channel" BaseType="microsoft.graph.entity">
  <Property Name="displayName" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="description" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="isFavoriteByDefault" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
  <Property Name="email" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="webUrl" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="membershipType" Type="microsoft.graph.channelMembershipType"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="messages" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.chatMessage)" ContainsTarget="true"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="chatThreads" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.chatThread)" ContainsTarget="true"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="tabs" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.teamsTab)" ContainsTarget="true"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="members" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.conversationMember)" ContainsTarget="true"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="filesFolder" Type="microsoft.graph.driveItem" ContainsTarget="true"/>
</EntityType>
```

You can call this using this template:

```
/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/filesFolder
```

This will return the Drive associated with a Private Channel:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('{teamsId}')/channels('{channelId}')/filesFolder/$entity",
    "id": "{id}",
    "createdDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-11-13T16:49:13Z",
    "name": "Private",
    "webUrl": "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{team}-Private/Shared%20Documents/{channel}",
    "size": 0,
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "{driveId}",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary"
    },
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2019-11-13T16:49:13Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-11-13T16:49:13Z"
    },
    "folder": {
        "childCount": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Marc is correct, documentation should be out shortly. Note that you cannot use the /teams route to retrieve the children, you'll need to fallback on the /drive route using the driveId in the response

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that the drive and site for the private channel is never generated until you actually visit the channel in the teams app. That one visit will trigger the creation of the drive and site. Im stuck here myself as i cannot trigger a private channel to created the SharePoint site and drive until i actually open the teams app and visit the channel.

Answer (score -1):

Currently /filesFolder for Private Channels returns BadGateway

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59673799/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Comment: The problem seems to be more complex...
 
It happens with the private channel that is deleted or I don't have permissions to (I don't know exactly).
 
I can't see this channel in Teams itself, but it is returned by /teams/<team-id>/channels API. And event /channels/<channel-id> endpoint is working... Looks like some permissions issue.